# Comparing List with Column and manipulating cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list called list_uid and it is all integers. I want to compare it to a sheet column called 'UID' using if and for loops. If it is true, then column on the sheet 'Completed?' will be updated to 'Y'. How am I able to do this?  I tried the scripts but it turns out that the whole column is full of 'Y's

```
for uid in list_uid:
    if uid in general['UID'].values:
        general['Complete'] = yes
    else:
        general['Complete'] = no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where` with a Boolean mask:

```
general['Complete'] = np.where(general['UID'].isin(list_uid), 'yes', 'no')
```

Alternatively you can map a Boolean series via a mapping dictionary:

```
d = {True: 'yes', False: 'no'}
general['Complete'] = general['UID'].isin(list_uid).map(d)
```